# My Proof for a Set Theory Question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

So, I have the following proof question that I'm doing and I'm hoping that someone can look over the structure of my proof and give me comments.

Let $A \subset U$ and $B \subset U$. Then, prove that $A \subset B \iff (U-B) \subset (U-A)$

---

```
    Proof
```

Let $A \subset U$ and $B \subset U$. Since the given proposition is a biconditional, we have to prove it in two directions.

We will, first, prove the following:

$A \subset B \implies (U-B) \subset (U-A)$

Let $x$ be an object such that $x \in U-B$. Then:

$x \in U-B \iff (x \in U) \land \lnot{(x \in B)}$

By the Law of Simplification:

$(x \in U) \land \lnot{(x \in B)} \implies \lnot{(x \in B)}$

$(x \in U) \land \lnot{(x \in B)} \implies (x \in U)$

Hence, it is true that $x \in U$ and $\lnot{(x \in B)}$. Since $A \subset B$, it follows that:

$A \subset B \iff \forall x \in U: \lnot{(x \in B)} \implies \lnot{(x \in A)}$

This shows that $\lnot{(x \in A)}$ is true. Hence, the following conjunction must be true as well:

$\lnot{(x \in A)} \land (x \in U) \iff (x \in U-A)$

That proves the forward conditional.

Now, we have to prove that:

$(U-B) \subset (U-A) \implies (A \subset B)$

Let $x$ be an object such that $x \in A$. Then, $x \in U$, since $A \subset U$. Hence, $\lnot{(x \in U-A)}$ is true. This implies that $\lnot{(x \in U-B)}$ is true as well as this is just the contrapositive of the hypothesis.

This just means that $x \in U-B$ must be false. Since we know that $x \in U$ is true, it follows that $\lnot{(x \in B)}$ must be false and, hence, $x \in B$ must be true. This proves that $A \subset B$.

By proving the conditionals in both directions, we have proven the original biconditional.

---

Seems like a rather long proof so I'm hoping to see a relatively shorter one suggested by someone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait but I still don't quite know if my proof holds up at each step. I'm quite confident that it does but.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For short proof:

$$A\not\subseteq B\iff \exists x\in U, s.t\ \ x\in A- B\iff x\in U, x\notin B \iff
    x\in U-B $$
$$A\not\subseteq B\iff\exists x\in U, s.t\ \ x\in A- B\iff x\not\in U-A$$

From both you obtain $$A\not\subseteq B\iff \exists x\in U, s.t\ \ x\in U-B, x\not\in U-A\iff U-B\not\subseteq U-A $$

Comment: Oh wow. That's very good. Is my proof correct?

Comment: The first part looks great, My math teachers always told me a mathematician should always try to be lazy, and not work too hard, so I didn't continue reading... sorry ;)

Comment: Oof rekt. Yea fair enough lol